# query string parameters for sitemap

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, querystringparameter, sitemapprovider, web.sitemap

I'm using VWD 2010, ASP.NET with C#.  I found a pointer for how to do this in another SO post.  Unfortunately, I can't get it working.

The sample code it points to is here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/adding-querystring-parameters-to-the-sitemapnode

I have included the C# code for this, but I can't seem to get the program to recognize that the code is actually there.  I set break points that never get invoked.
I put this into the web.config:

```
    <siteMap enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ExtendedSiteMapProvider" type="Configuration.ExtendedSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
<!--
        <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" name="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
    -->    
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

Notice how *AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider* is commented out.  That name appears nowhere else in the file.  Nevertheless when I attempt to run my program, I get this error message:
 *The provider 'AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider' specified for the defaultProvider does not exist in the providers collection.*

If I uncomment that line, the program runs, but the new code is never invoked.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not specifying the `defaultProvider` which defaults exactly to `AspNetXmlSiteMapProvide`, [like you can see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e333zt4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So you just have to specify the defualt provider like this:

```
<siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="ExtendedSiteMapProvider">
  <providers>
    ....
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Or specify the provider in corresponding `SiteMpaDataSource` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemapdatasource.provider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so that the default isn't used.

Comment: You have solved that problem.  I have a follow-on question, but I'm not sure whether I should open another question.  My problem now is that ExtendedSiteMapProvider does not seem to be invoked.  I have breakpoints defined, but they never break. In any case, thanks!

Comment: I think you should add a different question, explaining the new situation. Please, add there relevant code that shows the config, a little bit of the provider implementation, and the control which uses it (ASP.NET navigation control: breadcrumb, menu, tree...). It's clear the problem is now somewhere else.